# Get td value per tr upon clicking check box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to grab the id's from all td's that I have. Below is the my html table

```
<table class="dummyclass">
<tbody>
   <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' id='select_all'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>TestStatus</td>
        <td>TestDescription</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>101</td>
        <td>TestStatus1</td>
        <td>TestDescription1</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

and in the jquery function

```
 $('#select_all').live('click', function () {
        if(this.checked) {
      //  i need to fetch all id's from all td's 
      // 100,101   
}
});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `live()` has been deprecated for many years

Comment: @charlietfl ID is header i think he wants to get value of td under ID header. which is the first td

Comment: @guradio ooops...missed that. Thinking element id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traverse up to the ancestor `tr` by using `.closest()`, then use `.nextAll()` and `.find()` to get the `td` elements that have the IDs, then `.map()` with `toArray()` to create an array of the IDs.

```js
$('#select_all').live('click', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    var ids = $(this).closest("tr")
      .nextAll("tr")
      .find("td:first-child")
      .map(function(i, el) { return el.textContent })
     .toArray();
    console.log(ids);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="dummyclass">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Status</td>
      <td>Description</td>
      <td>CLICK ME: <input type='checkbox' id='select_all'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>TestStatus</td>
      <td>TestDescription</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>TestStatus1</td>
      <td>TestDescription1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also, putting your first row in a `thead` and the rest in a `tbody` would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should put your table header in `<thead></thead>`
2. Get ids by

```js
$('tbody td:first-child').map(function(index,ele){
  return $(ele).text()
}).toArray()
```

Comment: add `.get()` to convert to array but selector won't work as shown...only matches very first `<td>` of any `<tbody>`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily grab it by checking first column of the table.

Check this:

```
$('tr').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).find('td:first').text());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```js
$('#select_all').on('click', function(evt) {
  var ids = [];
  var $cells = $('tbody td:first-child');

  $cells.each(function() {
    ids.push(parseInt($(this).text(), 10));
  });

  console.log(ids);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type='button' id='select_all'>Select All</button>
  
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>TestStatus</td>
      <td>TestDescription</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>TestStatus1</td>
      <td>TestDescription1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that I converted your checkbox to a `<button>` element and moved it outside of the table, since it’s a UI element and not tabular data. I also updated the table to use `thead` and `th` for better accessibility and to make it easier to exclude the header cells.

Hope that helps!

P.S. If you need `live()` functionality, you can use event delegation and do something like `$('body').on('click', '#select_all', function(evt) { … });`

Comment: I like the idea of using `map()` like in Andy Chen’s solution, but same idea. This could also be done with plain JS, for what it's worth. Check out http://youmightnotneedjquery.com and https://plainjs.com